# Postgresql: Query is slow (9.5)

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.5

this is my query. I have more than 600000 rows of my table sale. I think the numbers of data is not too much, but it takes approximately 50s.
Here's the query.

> I need faster.

```
SELECT
st.product_id,
prd.price_in_stock,
prd.product_name_eng,
prd.currency_id,
prd.product_name_kh,
(SELECT quantity
    FROM daily_stock
    WHERE stock_id = st.stock_id
    AND DATE (stock_date) = DATE (now())
) AS pre_stock_quantity,
(SELECT SUM (trrc.quantity)
    FROM transfer trs
    INNER JOIN transfer_detail trd 
ON trs.transfer_id = trd.transfer_id
    INNER JOIN transfer_received trrc
ON trrc.transfer_detail_id = trd.transfer_detail_id
    WHERE
        trs.transfer_from = st.branch_id
    AND trd.product_id = st.product_id
    AND DATE (trrc.received_date) = DATE (NOW())
) AS trasfered_quantity,
(SELECT SUM (trrc.quantity)
    FROM transfer trs
    INNER JOIN transfer_detail trd 
ON trs.transfer_id = trd.transfer_id
    INNER JOIN transfer_received trrc
ON trrc.transfer_detail_id = trd.transfer_detail_id
    WHERE
        trs.transfer_to = st.branch_id
    AND trd.product_id = st.product_id
    AND DATE (trrc.received_date) = DATE (NOW())
) AS received_quantity,
(SELECT (SUM (smallest_devisor (sd.product_id) 
             * sd.quantity 
             / getDevisor (sd.product_id, sd.unit_id)))
         / smallest_devisor (sd.product_id) AS sold_quantity
    FROM
        sale_detail sd
    INNER JOIN sale sa ON sa.sale_id = sd.sale_id
    WHERE
        sa.branch_id = st.branch_id
    AND sd.product_id = st.product_id
    AND DATE (sa.sale_date) = DATE (NOW())
    GROUP BY
        sd.product_id
),
(SELECT (SUM(smallest_devisor (sd.product_id) 
             * rp.quantity 
             / getDevisor (sd.product_id, sd.unit_id))
        ) / smallest_devisor (sd.product_id) AS returned_quantity
    FROM
        returned_product rp
    INNER JOIN sale_detail sd ON sd.sale_detail_id = rp.sale_detail_id
    WHERE
        rp.branch_id = st.branch_id
    AND sd.product_id = st.product_id
    AND DATE (rp.returned_date) = DATE (NOW())
    GROUP BY
        sd.product_id
),
(
    SELECT
        SUM (quantity) AS imported_quantity
    FROM
        import
    WHERE
        branch_id = st.branch_id
    AND product_id = st.product_id
    AND DATE (import_date) = DATE (NOW())
),
st.quantity AS post_stock_quantity
FROM
stock st
INNER JOIN product prd ON prd.product_id = st.product_id
LEFT JOIN import imp ON imp.product_id = st.product_id
WHERE
   st.branch_id = 'BR0000';
```

analyze is here, I've seen the nested loop has taken cost much, but I don't know what to do more. I don't understand well about them, pls explain me some.

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=2.45..210929.10 rows=4 width=99) (actual time=845.040..68556.076 rows=22 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: ((st.product_id)::text = (imp.product_id)::text)
  Buffers: shared hit=2362098 read=499796, temp read=63910 written=63781
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.11..11.36 rows=4 width=99) (actual time=0.130..0.160 rows=5 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: ((st.product_id)::text = (prd.product_id)::text)
        Buffers: shared hit=11
        ->  Seq Scan on stock st  (cost=0.00..10.19 rows=4 width=23) (actual time=0.025..0.041 rows=5 loops=1)
              Filter: ((branch_id)::text = 'BR0000'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 10
              Buffers: shared hit=10
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.05..1.05 rows=5 width=114) (actual time=0.058..0.058 rows=5 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
              Buffers: shared hit=1
              ->  Seq Scan on product prd  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=5 width=114) (actual time=0.037..0.041 rows=5 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=1
  ->  Hash  (cost=1.15..1.15 rows=15 width=38) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=22 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        Buffers: shared hit=1
        ->  Seq Scan on import imp  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=15 width=38) (actual time=0.009..0.019 rows=22 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=1
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on daily_stock  (cost=0.00..48.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=22)
          Filter: ((stock_id = st.stock_id) AND (date(stock_date) = date(now())))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 29
          Buffers: shared hit=22
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=52.41..52.42 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=22)
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..52.41 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=22)
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..45.56 rows=1 width=60) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=22)
                      Join Filter: (trd.transfer_detail_id = trrc.transfer_detail_id)
                      ->  Seq Scan on transfer_received trrc  (cost=0.00..28.00 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=22)
                            Filter: (date(received_date) = date(now()))
                      ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..17.39 rows=3 width=56) (never executed)
                            ->  Seq Scan on transfer_detail trd  (cost=0.00..17.38 rows=3 width=56) (never executed)
                                  Filter: ((product_id)::text = (st.product_id)::text)
                ->  Index Scan using transfer_pkey on transfer trs  (cost=0.15..6.83 rows=1 width=52) (never executed)
                      Index Cond: ((transfer_id)::text = (trd.transfer_id)::text)
                      Filter: ((transfer_from)::text = (st.branch_id)::text)
  SubPlan 3
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=52.41..52.42 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=22)
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..52.41 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=22)
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..45.56 rows=1 width=60) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=22)
                      Join Filter: (trd_1.transfer_detail_id = trrc_1.transfer_detail_id)
                      ->  Seq Scan on transfer_received trrc_1  (cost=0.00..28.00 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=22)
                            Filter: (date(received_date) = date(now()))
                      ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..17.39 rows=3 width=56) (never executed)
                            ->  Seq Scan on transfer_detail trd_1  (cost=0.00..17.38 rows=3 width=56) (never executed)
                                  Filter: ((product_id)::text = (st.product_id)::text)
                ->  Index Scan using transfer_pkey on transfer trs_1  (cost=0.15..6.83 rows=1 width=52) (never executed)
                      Index Cond: ((transfer_id)::text = (trd_1.transfer_id)::text)
                      Filter: ((transfer_to)::text = (st.branch_id)::text)
  SubPlan 4
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=32059.02..52563.95 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=3116.048..3116.048 rows=0 loops=22)
          Group Key: sd.product_id
          Buffers: shared hit=2362020 read=499796, temp read=63910 written=63781
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=32059.02..52045.08 rows=1007 width=18) (actual time=830.903..988.696 rows=53521 loops=22)
                Hash Cond: ((sd.sale_id)::text = (sa.sale_id)::text)
                Buffers: shared hit=7084 read=499796, temp read=63910 written=63781
                ->  Seq Scan on sale_detail sd  (cost=0.00..19220.90 rows=201358 width=35) (actual time=0.079..193.761 rows=292880 loops=22)
                      Filter: ((product_id)::text = (st.product_id)::text)
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 512552
                      Buffers: shared hit=3520 read=197846
                ->  Hash  (cost=32008.68..32008.68 rows=4027 width=17) (actual time=552.758..552.758 rows=147183 loops=22)
                      Buckets: 131072 (originally 4096)  Batches: 4 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3137kB
                      Buffers: shared hit=3564 read=301950, temp written=10934
                      ->  Seq Scan on sale sa  (cost=0.00..32008.68 rows=4027 width=17) (actual time=400.100..500.394 rows=147183 loops=22)
                            Filter: (((branch_id)::text = (st.branch_id)::text) AND (date(sale_date) = date(now())))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 658225
                            Buffers: shared hit=3564 read=301950
  SubPlan 5
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.42..10.66 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=0 loops=22)
          Group Key: sd_1.product_id
          Buffers: shared hit=22
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..9.88 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=0 loops=22)
                Buffers: shared hit=22
                ->  Seq Scan on returned_product rp  (cost=0.00..1.43 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=0 loops=22)
                      Filter: (((branch_id)::text = (st.branch_id)::text) AND (date(returned_date) = date(now())))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 19
                      Buffers: shared hit=22
                ->  Index Scan using sale_detail_pkey on sale_detail sd_1  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=18) (never executed)
                      Index Cond: (sale_detail_id = rp.sale_detail_id)
                      Filter: ((product_id)::text = (st.product_id)::text)
  SubPlan 6
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=1.38..1.39 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.027..0.027 rows=1 loops=22)
          Buffers: shared hit=22
          ->  Seq Scan on import  (cost=0.00..1.38 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=0 loops=22)
                Filter: (((branch_id)::text = (st.branch_id)::text) AND ((product_id)::text = (st.product_id)::text) AND (date(import_date) = date(now())))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 22
                Buffers: shared hit=22
Planning time: 4.046 ms
Execution time: 68557.361 ms
```

Comment: Consider indexing your tables

Comment: Consider moving these select commands to `join` statements. Then check it against `explain analyze`

Comment: Right! Try to avoid subselects in the `SELECT` list. Try to use inner joins instead of outer joins wherever possible. Look at `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output and create indexes as needed. If you still have problems, post the query along with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: I have no idea to avoid sub selects in the case due to the aggregate functions need different rows of data from different tables.
I'll post the analyze in the edit version